# Chicken and Egg, Javascript Vs. Html Attribute

Tags: javascript

Long story short:

I'm building a js library.

While initializing the main object of the library, I'm trying to assign a value to a field. I have a parameter on the init object that is called in JavaScript and I have an attribute on the html tag (that I'm passing as a parameter to the init object as a jQuery object).

JavaScript call is:

```
Library($(".Target"), 500); <-- the 500 is the ArbitraryValue I'm looking at.
```

Html:

```
<div class="Target" ArbitraryValue="400">
    <!-- Trying to pass ArbitraryValue to the field. -->
</div>
```

My question is; Which would you expect to take precedence? 
Looking for some well thought out explanations here. 

I'm leaning toward a CSS style precedence where the attribute on the targeted html takes precedence vs the JavaScript called on said object. Am I right in thinking this way? I've been programming in so many other languages (C++, C, VB, C#) and I just want to nail this down but want the group consensus here...after all, I'm writing this library so that it may be re-used, one day.

Comment: I think you're making things much complicated it really is... if you have html code before js, then html will assign it to 400, then js will override it and make it 500. if js is loaded fist, then js will fail and complain b/c div not found, html will assign it to 500?

Comment: Everyone that has posted above this message, I ask you to take a good look at your responses and tell me how helpful you think they are. Candidly I will say, they were not but I am open to you explaining your responses. I will recant my reports on your posts if you can articulate your meaning intelligently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of JS I would say that you should have your library use HTML IF there is nothing in the call (i.e.)

```
Library($(".Target"));
```

However, if there is, then use the JS initialization.

From my experience that is how a lot of JS libraries work.

To explain my thinking.  setting as a HTML attribute makes me think that it should 'just work' out the box.  Usually when you initialise something with JS options, it is because those options are not known until after runtime (usually due to some user interaction etc etc). Think of HTML as a set of plans of how things `should` be, and JS as direct orders to CHANGE how things `should` be.

Comment: Mat Taylor,

I really appreciate your response, I entirely agree with your point.